# Increment Query for Features & User Stories in ADO

Tags: azure-devops

I'm creating a view in Azure DevOps for Increment Planning. I want to display all Features that have scheduled work for the next 6 sprints. The Feature might not be scheduled to complete in that time, but one or more User Stories are.

I want to create a Feature/User Story tree view with items displayed as follows:

- All Features whose iteration path is within the next 6 sprints, with User Stories under them, in tree view.
- All Features that have a User Story within them whose iteration path is within the next 6 sprints, in tree view.

In practical terms, it should:

- Display any Feature that has an iteration path of 1908-2, 1909-1, 1909-2, 1910-1, 1910-2, 1911-1 regardless of if it has User Stories under it.
- And it should display any User Story that has an iteration path of 1908-2, 1909-1, 1909-2, 1910-1, 1910-2, 1911-1 under its Feature (regardless of the iteration path of the Feature).
- So a Feature with an iteration path of 1911-2 or anywhere in the future (such as 2006-02) should display, IF it has a User Story with an iteration path of 1908-2, 1909-1, 1909-2, 1910-1, 1910-2 or 1911-1.

I've been able to write a query that returns all Features (and their Stories) within iterations 0-5, but this doesn't return any Features outside of this range if they have Stories that are within the range.

Here's the query: Features > Iterations 0-5 > User Stories as Child
[image]

And the results: Obviously, just Features within Iterations 0-5
[image]

The problem is, there are Features (like this one) that have User Stories within the increment that aren't being returned, because the Feature's iteration isn't within range, even though the User Stories are.
[image]

Here's a query that returns all Features and only User Stories within iterations 0-5:
[image]

As you can see, this returns Features (with no User Stories) outside of this range:
[image]

I need to see ALL work that is scheduled to be completed over the next 6 sprints, in a Feature/User Story tree view. If I were able to use If/Then, I don't see this being a problem. But I'm having a very hard time figuring it out with And/Or...

Comment: I also think it hard to query out with tree view , you can try wiql to see if it work.

Comment: I don't know WIQL, but if time permits I'll look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using the State in the query. A Feature won't have User Stories under it unless it is Active. So, by filtering out New and items that are in the Backlog, it results in all work.

I expanded my query to include Scenarios and here is what it looks like:

[image]